# python line.split semantic error fromtext file

Tags: python, string

this section of code is supposed to make a list containing the values of the second column in the text file, but it takes the second letter. anyone know what my problem is?

```
TEXTFILE  
opi 60  
kid 60  
pou 60  
ret 60  
kai 60  
bob 100  

for line in lst:                          
    line.split(' ')  
    fire.append(int(line[1]))
    print(line[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do something like this:

```
mylist = []

for line in file:
    firstcolval, secondcolval = line.split()
    mylist.append(int(firstcolval))
```

Answer (score 1):

This should also work

```
import csv
for line in csv.reader(open("datafile"), delimiter=" "):                          
    fire.append(int(line[1]))
    print(line[1])
```

Alternatively

```
from operator import itemgetter
import csv
f=csv.reader(open("datafile"),delimiter=' ')
fire+=[int(x[1]) for x in f]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
line.split(' ')
```

Your mistake is there, the `split` doesn't split `line` but returns a line split. So instead what you need to do is

```
columns = line.split(' ')
```

and use columns instead

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple one liner.

```
fire = [int(b) for a, b in line.split(" ") for line in lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so since split creates a new object (list containing at least one element), you should do:

```
for line in lst:
    lc = line.split(' ')
    fire.append(int(lc[1]))
    print lc[1]
```

But as someone has already suggested, you can do that in one line, with list comprehension:

```
newlist = [int(current[1]) for current in line.split(" ") for line in lst]
```

Which reads like: for ever line in lst we split the line with whitespace, and add element with index one from splitted line (current[1]) converted to int, to our new list.